# Is there a way to change to div position via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to know what if is there a way to change the position of elements via jquery?
This is the sample cod:

```
<div>
    <div class='first-class'></div>
    <div class='second-class'></div>
</div>
```

I need it change to:

```
<div>
    <div class='second-class'></div>
    <div class='first-class'></div>
</div>
```

without changing in code can I do that with jquery?
Thanks

Comment: You could just swap the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
$('.second-class').after($('.first-class'))
```

OR

```
$('.first-class').before($('.second-class'))
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/47/)

Comment: Sorry.The content is shown as before. it didn't changed.

Comment: @user3104188 updated my answer, it had gone vice-versa. And added demo after clicking the button it will swap.